# Is there a way to make an ExecutorService work recursively?

Tags: java

I made the following mistake:

1. Called `Executors.newFixedThreadThreadPool` to make a pool
2. Set up a list of `Callable` objects, such that the `call` method in turn tried to start a task on the *very same thread pool*
3. dump them into the queue with `invokeAll`

The results were a deadlock on the queue of the executor service.

The Javadoc I've read doesn't appear to prohibit this set of activities. Did I miss something? Is there some way to customize the queue or the service so that this could work?

Comment: I had a similar question. Let's say my thread pool has only a single thread in it. My outer Callable gets the thread and invokes a sub-task Callable. It then waits for the sub-task to complete. However, since the only thread in the pool is already associated with the outer task, it will never be assigned to the inner task, resulting in deadlock. Is this assessment correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: After thinking about this a bit more, it seems that you could get into deadlock if the number of branches (i.e. the number of tasks that spawn sub-tasks) is greater than the number of threads in the pool. So, when your branch count exceeds the thread count, you could just execute the sub-tasks serially rather than submitting them for parallel execution. I haven't tried this but conceptually it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of your question is something like the following test-case, which works as documented (as you say) and I've happily used in production.  How does your example differ from this?

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        pool.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                pool.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws Exception {
                        System.out.println(new Date() + ": Second callable being run.");
                        pool.shutdown();
                        return null;
                    }
                });

                System.out.println(new Date() + ": First callable going to sleep...");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println(new Date() + ": First callable finished!");
                return null;
            }
        });

        pool.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

Prints something like:

```
Mon Feb 20 01:18:00 GMT 2012: First callable going to sleep...
Mon Feb 20 01:18:02 GMT 2012: First callable finished!
Mon Feb 20 01:18:02 GMT 2012: Second callable being run.
```

Comment: My outer function is using pool.invokeAll, not pool.submit, so it is waiting. And I suspect now that the problem is that all the threads are used up on the 'outer' threads, so no work gets done inside. In other words, I was an idiot.

Comment: Even so, an executing Callable should still be able to `submit()` a new Callable (as `submit()` never blocks on a `newFixedThreadPool()`)?  Unless you were using `pool.invokeAll()` inside the Callables too?

Comment: That's inside lucene and I don't know. But if all the threads were used up on the outside, the inside can submit, but never progress, and then none of the outsides will ever complete either.